# Pattern matching on a list with at least two elements in Elm

Tags: elm

What is wrong with the following pattern matching on a list with at least two elements `pos1` and `pos2`?

```
type Pos = (Float, Float)
type Tail = [Pos]

tail_cut : Float -> Tail -> Tail
tail_cut _ [] = []
tail_cut _ [pos] = [pos]
tail_cut cut (pos1:pos2:poss) = []   --line 91

[1 of 1] Compiling Main
Parse error at (line 91, column 19):
unexpected ":"
expecting "::", pattern, whitespace, comma ',' or closing paren ')'
```

Note that I didn't post the body and just return an empty list in order to keep the fragment small.

Comment: Note that Elm [no longer supports](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/973) multi-line function definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Elm, `cons` is defined as `::` rather than `:`

See: http://library.elm-lang.org/catalog/elm-lang-Elm/0.13/List

This should do it: `(pos1::pos2::poss)`

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is no longer valid for Elm >= 0.15, which no longer supports multi-line function definitions. I've gotten rid of the types to provide a more general answer.

```
tailMatch : a -> List a -> List a
tailMatch el list =
  case (el, list) of
    (_, []) -> 
      []
    (_, head :: []) ->
      []
    (el, head1 :: head2 :: tail) ->
      []
```

The second pattern can be written as `(_, [head]) ->` if you find that more readable.